# Given three angle bisectors with the incenter and one vertex, how to construct triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Given  three lines $l,m,n$ with one intersection point $O$, and one point $A$ on line $m$. Prove that there exist a triangle which has three angle bisectors $l,m,n$ and one vertex $A$. I tried to draw a circle with center $O$, which should be tangent to the three sides, But I can not prove it, namely the circle should be tangent with the opposite side $BC$.

**Accurate Original Wording :**

[image: ORIGINAL]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the Question from ? Why did you want to Solve the Question ? What did you try ?

Comment: This is the problem 38 from J. Hadamard geometry.

Comment: Do angle chasing at the incenter, to realize that $ \angle BID = (\alpha + \beta ) / 2$ and $\angle CID  = (\alpha + \gamma) / 2$, hence we can recover $\alpha$ by reflecting line $l$ across $n$. Bisect this angle, and construct it off both sides of $m$ at $A$.

Comment: @jjagmath Ah yes, I was mixing it up with the circumcircle, as $A$ is a vertex of the triangle rather than a point of tangency of the circle.

Comment: OP gave the Question inaccurately , missing several Points : (A) lines are all Distinct (B) Prove the Existence of the triangle , not necessarily Construct it (C) Bisectors may be Interior or Exterior (D) With all that , there is 1 Exception ! I will try including these in Post.

Comment: @prem thanks for your correction.

Comment: Each of those Criteria are very necessary , @CraigThone , (A) When lines are not Distinct , there may be multiple Solutions (B) Showing Existence may be Possible even when there is no theoretical Construction (C) Interior Solution may not Exist when Exterior Solution Exists (D) We have to show the Exception Case.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I am giving as an answer what Calvin Lin put into the comments. But there are some subtle points related to the possibility that the intended incenter could turn into an excenter!

Let $B$ lie on $l$ and $C$ lie on $n$. Then side $\overline{BC}$ makes angle measuring $\frac12\angle B$ with $l$ and $\frac12\angle C$ with $n$. From the angle chasing described by Calvin, you find that in $\triangle OBC$ the vertalex angle at $O$ measures $90°+\frac12\angle A$.

So to get the *half*-angle at $A$, subtract a right angle from the angle between $l$ and $n$ in the quadrant opposite $A$. Then:

- $B$ lies on $l$ such that $\angle OAB$ measures the required half-angle and line $n$ passes between $A$ and $B$ (this betweenness criterion is necessary for $O$ to be an incenter).
- $C$ lies on $n$ such that $\angle OAC$ measures the required half-angle and line $l$ passes between $A$ and $B$.

Now comes the subtle part, which (to my eyes anyway) is suggested by the diagram in the original question. $\angle BOC$, defined above from lines $l$ and $n$, could measure *less than* $90°$! When this happens, the half-angle at $A$, as determined from the above procedure, becomes negative!

In geometry, a negative quantity implies a reversal of orientation. Here that takes the form of $B$ and $C$ still lying on $l$ and $n$ as defined above, except $n$ now passes outside $\overline{AB}$ (beyond $B$) and $l$ passes outside $\overline{AC}$ (beyond $C$). Therefore, $O$ now lies *outside* the constructed triangle and the intended bisectors $l$ and $n$ end up bisecting exterior angles at $B$ and $C$. This reversal turns $O$ into the *excenter opposite $A$* when the angle between $l$ and $n$ in the quadrantbopposite $A$ measures less than $90°$.

Comment: The Points you raise about Subtle Part & Excenter are covered in Question itself now. There is 1 Exception which is when the given Configuration will give **Parallel lines** , "meeting" at infinity.

Comment: @Prem if $l$ and $n$ are perpendicular I do not see how there would be parallel lines. With the half-angle at $A$ reduced to zero the triangle seems to look like a doubled-back line segment.

Comment: Consider this [[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMB14.png ]] where the lines $1$ & $2$ & $3$ meet at $O$ , lines $1$ & $3$ are at $90^0$ , with line $2$ Bisecting that $90^0$ to get $45^0$ & the line $1$ has the Point $A$. The other $3$ lines are the "triangle" around the "In-Circle" , though the angles are $90^0$ & $90^0$ & $0^0$ : the Parallel lines "meet" at Infinity !

Comment: If I understand correctly, after you find point $B$ and $C$, you need to prove that $OB$ and $OC$ are bisectors. Am I right?

Comment: What is there to prove? The angle measures and betweenness relations (the latter depending on whether the angle between $l$ and $n$ opposite $A$ is acute or obtuse) are suffucient to define the directions of $\overline{AB}$
 and $\overline{AC}$ uniquely.